# Why does this code gives off a "segmentation fault"?

Tags: arrays, memory, segmentation-fault, cs50, edges

This code is from cs50 filter's problem set. I checked that each line of code doesn't try to access a memory it shouldn't have, but it always yielded a segmentation fault.

Here is the code:

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int Gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int Gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
    int Gx_red = 0;
    int Gx_blue = 0;
    int Gx_green = 0;
    int Gy_red = 0;
    int Gy_blue = 0;
    int Gy_green = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= (width - 2); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= (height - 2); j++) {

            for (int m = i - 1; m <= i + 1; m++) {
                for (int n = j - 1; n <= j + 1; n++) {
                    Gx_red += image[m][n].rgbtRed * Gx[m - (i - 1)][n - (j - 1)];
                    Gx_blue += image[m][n].rgbtBlue * Gx[m - (i - 1)][n - (j - 1)];
                    Gx_green += image[m][n].rgbtGreen * Gx[m - (i - 1)][n - (j - 1)];
                    Gy_red += image[m][n].rgbtRed * Gy[m - (i - 1)][n - (j - 1)];
                    Gy_blue += image[m][n].rgbtBlue * Gy[m - (i - 1)][n - (j - 1)];
                    Gy_green += image[m][n].rgbtGreen * Gy[m - (i - 1)][n - (j - 1)];

                }
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sqrt((pow(Gx_red,2) + pow(Gy_red, 2))));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sqrt(pow(Gx_blue, 2) + pow(Gy_blue, 2)));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sqrt(pow(Gx_green, 2) + pow(Gy_green, 2)));
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Can anyone detect the problem?

Comment: what does height and width contain?

Comment: the height and width of the image, like for example if it was image[15][20], then image has 15 horizontal pixels and 20 vertical pixels, but of course the last horizontal pixel would be 14 because couting in arrays starts at 0.

Comment: your indexes for Gr dereived from w and w go way outside 3*3

Comment: You mean indexes derived from the variables "m" and "n"?

Comment: yes, i meant widthe and hieght